# Need to sort columns based on row

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort columns based on first row. Can anyone help me in achieve this for example. Basically I have a csv.

I have a matrix like:-

```
B,    C,    D,    E,    A
1,    11,   12,   23,   67
111,  112,  114,  118,  200
```

I want this matrix to be sorted using row 1, so A should come at first and so the same columns in other rows.

```
A,    B,   C,     D,   E   
67,   1,   11,    12,   23
200,  111, 112,  114,  118


CSV Input:-  B,C,D,E,A\n1,11,12,23,67\n,111,112,114,118,200
CSV Output:- A,B,C,D,E\n67,1,11,12,23\n,200,111,112,114,118
```

Can someone help me or guide me how to achieve the same.

Comment: What have you tried? Matrix of what? Is this input from stdin?

Comment: This is an input from csv.

Comment: You could make an double array and move the columns based on the top row by making a quick sorting algorithm (not to be confused with quicksort algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't provided us with any of your code, I won't be able to do more than explain one solution.  Assume you have the following matrix, which can potentially be stored in an `Object[][]` where `Object` is the type of whatever you're concerned with:

```
Object[][] = [
    [B,   C,   D,   E,   A  ],
    [1,   11,  12,  23,  67 ],
    [111, 112, 114, 118, 200]
]
```

You can now take the transpose of the matrix, which results in the following:

```
Object[][] = [
    [B, 1,  111],
    [C, 11, 112],
    [D, 12, 114],
    [E, 23, 118],
    [A, 67, 200]
]
```

Now, simply sort this matrix by the first element of each row to produce the following:

```
Object[][] = [
    [A, 67, 200],
    [B, 1,  111],
    [C, 11, 112],
    [D, 12, 114],
    [E, 23, 118]
]
```

Finally, if you would like it back in its original form, take the transpose once again:

```
Object[][] = [
    [A,   B,   C,   D,   E  ],
    [67,  1,   11,  12,  23 ],
    [200, 111, 112, 114, 118]
]
```

If you provide us with some of your code showing us how you store the data contained in the CSV, then I can help you write the code.

Comment: basically it won't be a matrix, I get input as mentioned CSV Input. I ain't getting any matrix as of now.

Comment: @DisplayName Your CSV input can be represented as a matrix, so I recommend you deserialize it into one.